# C/Posix Questions

Tags: c, posix, jamvm

I have been working for two weeks on JamVM, a small but powerful Java Virtual Machine.

Now I am trying to figure how the memory is implemented and I am stuck on two C stupid problems:

`char *mem = (char*)mmap(0, args->max_heap, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON, -1, 0);`

--> The -1 parameter stands for a file descriptor, what does that mean? (I have aleady read the mmap man, but haven't found it, maybe I misunderstood...).

`heapbase = (char*)(((uintptr_t)mem+HEADER_SIZE+OBJECT_GRAIN-1&)~(OBJECT_GRAIN-1)) HEADER_SIZE;`

--> What is 1& ? I don't find it in the C specification...

Thanks,

Yann

Comment: If this were two separate questions, then you'd be able to give each one a useful title.

Comment: `-1&)~(` is not even legal C (a compiler should complain about a missing token), are you sure its not `-1)&~(`? which means AND NOT, (usually used to turn a specific bit off)

Comment: @Wiz: In this case, OBJECT_GRAIN is probably a power of 2, so if the code were `-1)&~` then it would round `mem+HEADER_SIZE` up to the next multiple of `OBJECT_GRAIN`.

Comment: Yeah I am sure, I copied the source code! If it was a mistake, there maybe a warning a compile no?

Comment: @Steve: Yes OBJECT_GRAIN is for data alignment, it's equal to 8

Comment: @scoobyclown i beg to differ: (line 212) http://read.pudn.com/downloads144/sourcecode/others/628545/jamvm-1.4.2/jamvm-1.4.2/src/alloc.c__.htm (I guess it must be a typo in the source you are viewing)

Comment: @scoobyclown: please accept an answer that solves your question instead of editing that into the title. Stackoverflow.com is not a forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the file descriptor when you have an open file that you want to map into memory. In this case, you're creating an anonymous map (one not backed by a file) so the file descriptor isn't needed. Some implementations ignore `fd` for anonymous maps, some *require* it to be -1.

The second question is a syntax error (probably a typo). It probably should be something like:

```
heapbase = (char*)(((uintptr_t)mem+HEADER_SIZE+OBJECT_GRAIN-1)
    &~(OBJECT_GRAIN-1)) - HEADER_SIZE;
```

In that case, `OBJECT_GRAIN` will be a power of two and it's a way to get alignment to that power. For example, if it were 8, then `~(OBJECT_GRAIN-1)` would be `~7` (`~00...001112`, which is `~11...110002`) which, when ANDed with a value, could be used to force that value to the multiple-of-8 less than or equal to it.

In fact, it's definitely a transcription error somewhere (not necessarily you) because, when I download the JamVM from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jamvm/files/) and look in `src/alloc.c`, I get:

```
void initialiseAlloc(InitArgs *args) {
    char *mem = (char*)mmap(0, args->max_heap, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                                               MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
    :
    << a couple of irrelevant lines >>
    :    
    /* Align heapbase so that start of heap + HEADER_SIZE is object aligned */
    heapbase = (char*)(((uintptr_t)mem+HEADER_SIZE+OBJECT_GRAIN-1)&
               ~(OBJECT_GRAIN-1))-HEADER_SIZE;
```

(note that your version is also missing the `-` immediately before `HEADER_SIZE`, something else that points to transcription problems).

Comment: Thank you, That's it! But it's strange because I have the latest version and it works fine...

Comment: After downloading a clean copy of JamVM and apply a diff, the only difference seems to be the line with heapbase... I maybe have made bad edits while reading... Thanks for your answer and sorry !

Comment: @scooby, no need to apologise, helping people is why we are here. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

In answer to your first question.  From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap).

> fd should be a valid file descriptor, unless MAP_ANONYMOUS is set. If MAP_ANONYMOUS is set, then fd is ignored on Linux. However, some implementations require fd to be -1 if MAP_ANONYMOUS (or MAP_ANON) is specified, and portable applications should ensure this.

So it's -1 because `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is being used.

Comment: Thanks! That why I said it was a stupid question in the first place, I hadn't read the good manual in the first place (I read the 3p)